# django Q as chained .filter()

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

There are 2 models connected with a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Record():
    working_on_record = models.ManyToManyField(
        UserProfile, related_name="working_on_record", blank=True)

class UserProfile():
    name = CharField...
```

The UserProfile is just a basic user model.

Now I want to query a search for records and check if **all** keywords are matched but if I do:

```
query = Q()
c1 = UserProfile.objects.filter(name__icontains='peter')
query.add(Q(working_on_record__in=c1), Q.AND)

c2 = UserProfile.objects.filter(name__icontains='john')
query.add(Q(working_on_record__in=c2), Q.AND)

set3 = list(models.Record.objects.filter(query))
```

Set3 is empty, despite there is a record which has two people working on it whose names are "john smith" and "peter parker". If I replace "john" in c2 by "parker" I get **all** records where "peter parker" is working on it.

But if I chain the filter methods:

```
set4 = list(models.Record.objects
            .filter(working_on_record__in=c1)
            .filter(working_on_record__in=c2)
       )
```

set4 is not empty and contains the record I want.

Is it possible to change the Q-query so that I get the behavior I want?
Is it possible to filter with a Q-query on one many-to-many-relationship with different values from different objects connected with an AND?

I don't like the idea of chaining the filter methods, because of multiple possible usages of the Q-query, so I would have to iterate at multiple occasions through all queries and chain them.

Comment: That is logical, in the former you specify that the *same* `working_on_record` should be a member of both sets.

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain it with an example? 
I want to get the records, on which "john" is working on **and** "peter" is working on, but they are two distinct users, which apparently doesn't work, because the Q-query searches for "john" and "peter" **on the same** user.

Comment: By using `Model.objects.filter(foo=bar).filter(foo=qux)`, you make *two* joins, and thus you state "Look for Model objects where there is a foo that is bar, and a foo that is qux), whereas a filter `Model.objects(Q(foo=bar) & Q(foo=qux))` says, "look for a Model whit a related Foo that is both bar and qux".

Comment: Ok thank you very much! 
But is there a way to achieve joining with Q?

Comment: Do you need the created Q object later on or do you only use it for the one query?

Comment: I use it for one or two queries depending on the user permissions. I need the q object itself, because I have some ORs which are connected (to search fulltext in multiple fields of the record).